# Error in laravel mix node_modules css-loader

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to use sass loader in laravel mix 4.1.2

I tried to install node-sass and sass-loader both are showing same error

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ServerTestEs/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:49:11)
    at Object.loader (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ServerTestEs/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:36:28)

I want to enable sass loader to make sure to use lazy loading [dynamic importing ] of components in vue

Comment: add your code of your webpack config please

Comment: @TonyNgo i am using laravel mix. do you want to see package.json